# Connect Tableau Public to Firebase using Tableau Web Data Connector

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, tableau-api

I have some data hosted in Google Firebase and I need to make some analysis using Tableau Public (free version). And the Tableau data should be updated daily.

I read that a possible solution could be using a Tableau Web Data Connector but I'm not sure of this. If I use the Tableau WDC is there a way to schedule the data update? As far as I have understood a Tableau WCD is an intermediate page that downloads the data for example from a rest API and then put them into a tableau page. 
Is it the correct way to achieve my goal?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not achievable through Tableau Public.

If you were using Tableau Desktop,
Currently as of 05/16/2018, there is no official connector for firebase. Also, I do not see third-party Tableau Web Data connector for firebase yet.

A Tableau WDC is a html page consisting of javascript hosted on a webserver and grabs data for you through http and returns it to the machine where you entered in the URL for the specified WDC.

[An alternative would be to import your firebase data into BigQuery. Then, accessing your data from there.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query)

Comment: Unfortunately Tableau public doesn't give you the possibility to use BigQuery as datasource.

Comment: @Paolo were you able to solve the problem? I am also trying to do the same and would like to know how you were able to connect to tableau using WDC and firebase

Comment: Yes, I did it exposing the data on a public branch of firebase database, then I implemented a WDC page that I used into Tableau Public to grab the data. The only issue is that Tableau is not able to update the graphs automatically; you must update it manually.